# Dynamically Insert Value Into a Comment String With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I insert tomorrow's `day`'s `startTime` and `endTime` into the content message for the `setupOrderingNotAvailable` function if today's `day` has an `endTime` that has expired?  Right now the message `setupOrderingNotAvailable` says "...again tomorrow from 11:00am to 9:00pm" but that is not true for every day; this is where I would like to insert tomorrow's times.

**Code**

```
var days = {
    '1': {startTime: '4:00 PM', endTime: '8:00 PM'},
    '2': {startTime: '11:00 AM', endTime: '9:00 PM'},
    '3': {startTime: '11:00 AM', endTime: '9:00 PM'},
    '4': {startTime: '11:00 AM', endTime: '4:00 PM'},
    '5': {startTime: '11:00 AM', endTime: '10:00 PM'},
    '6': {startTime: '12:00 PM', endTime: '10:00 PM'},
    '7': {startTime: '12:00 PM', endTime: '8:00 PM'},
};

var curr_day = new Date().getDay();
var curr_time = getval();
var orderIsAvailable = false;
var day = days[curr_day];

// 
function setupOrderingAvailable() {
    document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
        $.sweetModal({
            content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Available!</h2>' +
                'Please click the button below to begin your online order.' +
                '<div class="sweet-modal-buttons"><a href="http://pizzospizzeria.hungerrush.com" target="_blank" class="button greenB">Start Order</a></div>',
            // icon: $.sweetModal.ICON_SUCCESS
        });
    };
}

// Need to make this a function that inserts tomorrows startTime and endTime into message if todays endTime has passed
function setupOrderingNotAvailable() {
    document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
        $.sweetModal({
            content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Not Available</h2>' +
                'Online ordering will be available again tomorrow from 11:00am to 9:00pm',
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Close',
                classes: 'redB'
            }]
        });
    };
}
if (day) {
    if (get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(day.startTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(day.endTime)) {
        orderingIsAvailable = true;
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#alert-success').onclick = function() {
            $.sweetModal({
                content: '<h2>Online Ordering is Not Available</h2>' +
                    'Online ordering will be available again tomorrow from 11:00am to 9:00pm',
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'Close',
                    classes: 'redB'
                }]
            });
        }
    }
}

if (orderingIsAvailable) {
    setupOrderingAvailable();
} else {
    setupOrderingNotAvailable();
}
```

Comment: so, uhm... where's the json string? did you mean object? the two are not the same.

Comment: sorry, the content message.

Comment: Get the times from tomorrow's `day` and concatenate then into the message. Are you not sure how to combine strings?

Comment: thanks @MikeMcCaughan - I know how to combine strings, just not clear on how to display tomorrows data based on todays.

Comment: Well, it appears as though you're getting today's `day` by using `new Date().getDay()`, so tomorrow's `day` would use `new Date().getDay() + 1`, right?

Comment: If you're keeping track of what day is today, then you know tomorrow is +1 as far as the object key goes. That'll let you reference the correct data from the days object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the time comparison code a little by determining the time in ms for the start and end time. This allows a cleaner (IMO) comparison of the time *right now* as a number vs the start and end times. The day integer returned from the Date object ranges from 0-6, so I updated that too.

From there you do the comparison and if ordering can't happen now

Here's a fiddle, albeit with the sweetModal aspect stripped out, but the string is created just the same no matter how you display it.

https://jsfiddle.net/wx97g6x1/2/

```
var days = {
  0: {
    startTime: '4:00 PM',
    endTime: '8:00 PM'
  },
  1: {
    startTime: '11:00 AM',
    endTime: '9:00 PM'
  },
  2: {
    startTime: '11:00 AM',
    endTime: '9:00 PM'
  },
  3: {
    startTime: '11:00 AM',
    endTime: '4:00 PM'
  },
  4: {
    startTime: '11:00 AM',
    endTime: '10:00 PM'
  },
  5: {
    startTime: '12:00 PM',
    endTime: '10:00 PM'
  },
  6: {
    startTime: '12:00 PM',
    endTime: '8:00 PM'
  }
};

var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
var day = days[now.getDay()];

var startToday = Date.parse(now.toDateString() + ' ' + day.startTime);
var endToday = Date.parse(now.toDateString() + ' ' + day.endTime);

function setupOrderingAvailable() {
  console.log('Online Ordering is Available!');
}

function setupOrderingNotAvailable() {
  var tomorrow = days[now.getDay() + 1];
  console.log('Online ordering will be available again tomorrow from '+ tomorrow.startTime +' to '+ tomorrow.endTime)
}

if (time > startToday && time < endToday) {
  setupOrderingAvailable();
} else {
  setupOrderingNotAvailable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
const days = {
    '1': { start: 1, end: 2 },
    '2': { start: 3, end: 4 }
}
const string = `day 2 starts at: ${days['2'].start} and ends at: ${days['2'].end}`
console.log(string); // "day 2 starts at: 3 and ends at: 4"
```

In addition to using the fact that each day's "value" is 1 greater than the previous.